# Deploying multiple APK with vector asset (android)

Tags: android, apk

android studio is currently supporting [vector assets](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html). according to the literature I can

> Create separate APKs for different API levels. When you don’t include
>   the corresponding raster images in the APK for Android 5.0 (API level
>   21) and higher, the APK can be much smaller in size. For more
>   information, see Multiple APK Support.

so I tried creating 2 APIs: -

- the pre-lollipop version contains the generated pngs without the vector assets,
- while the lollipop version contains only the vectors assets

In http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

> If an APK you've uploaded for API levels 4 and above (Android 1.6+) has a version code of 0400, then an APK for API levels 8 and above (Android 2.2+) must be 0401 or greater. In this case, the API level is the only supported filter used, so the version codes must increase in correlation with the API level support for each APK, so that users get an update when they receive a system update.

The following is my gradle build file.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "twitch.angelandroidapps.matchit"
}
productFlavors { 
    lollipopConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "21.1.0"
    }
    preLollipopConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        maxSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 2
        versionName "10.1.0"
    }
} 
:
//snipped the rest of the build config...
:
```

however, when I deploy the pre-lollipop version first, followed by the lollipop version, then the pre-lollipop version got archived (and vice-versa).

Any advice on how I can get both versions to be deployed in the play store?

Comment: I mixed the deployment order up... it's lollipop -> pre-lollipop-> lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

I had it figured out.

When i first deploy the lollipops and pre-lollipops, they get auto-archived.

For some strange reason, I have to manually shift the pre-lollipop version back into production by clicking "Move to Prod" for it to work.

[image]

After that, the playstore will show a new "API LEVELS" column.

[image]

Also the literature about having a larger versionCode seems to be wrong. Pre-lollipop version needs to always be a lower VersionCode (probably because my API levels do not overlap?). Anyway, I can now deploy new pre-lollipop versions without getting the previous version archived.

[image]

In the end, I used the naming convention of

- 21xxxx for lollipop versions and
- 10xxxx for pre-lollipop versions

[image]

Hope it helps.